# JTextField together with HTML tags

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextfield

I am working on Java 7. I am trying to format text by using HTML tags. I pass in text into

```
JTextField text = new JTextField();
text.setText("<html><body><p>The program performs encryption operations on the following ciphers: </p></body></html>");
```

But the program prints the HTML tags too. That sample of text  is only an example.
What might be the problem?
Cheers

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a `JTextField`? If you just want to display some text, a [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) is better suited.

Comment: I have seen on some links that HTML tags work fine on JTextField too. It looks like text field looks better on my app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`JTextField` does [not support HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915061/html-in-jtextarea-of-jeditorpane-jtextpane). You could use `JTextPane` instead:

```
JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
text.setContentType("text/html");
text.setText("<html><body><p>The program performs encryption operations on the following ciphers: </p></body></html>");
```