# How to Change the font of Textfield using a variable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, fonts, joptionpane

Can any one tell me how to change the font of a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 after getting the value of the `jTextFields` so that if i show it on my `JOptionPane` the assign value of each variable has colors

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String a1 = jTextField1.getText();
    String a2 = jTextField2.getText();
    String a3 = jTextField3.getText();
    String a4 = jTextField4.getText();
    String a5 = jTextField5.getText();

    String m1 = "You will never forget " + a1 + "\n\n";
    String m2 = "You can consider " + a2 + " as your true friend \n\n";
    String m3 = "You really Love " + a3 + "\n\n";
    String m4 = a4 + " is your twin soul \n\n" ; 
    String m5 = "you will remember " + a5 + " for the rest of your life (due to past –good or bad- experiences, lessons etc) \n\n";
    String m6 = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,m6);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create Label, set Font, and then use it to create messageDialog.
Try something like this:

```
String a1 = jTextField1.getText();
String a2 = jTextField2.getText();
String a3 = jTextField3.getText();
String a4 = jTextField4.getText();
String a5 = jTextField5.getText();

String m1 = "You will never forget " + a1 + "\n\n";
String m2 = "You can consider " + a2 + " as your true friend \n\n";
String m3 = "You really Love " + a3 + "\n\n";
String m4 = a4 + " is your twin soul \n\n" ; 
String m5 = "you will remember " + a5 + " for the rest of your life (due to past –good or bad- experiences, lessons etc) \n\n";
String m6 = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5;

JLabel label = new JLabel(m6);
label.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label);
```

Comment: is there any Import that should i call? because there are no JLabel when i type it

Comment: Yes, 'javax.swing.JLabel' if you're using Eclipse, there is a nice shortcut "ctrl + shift + o" to add all imports you need :

Comment: Also consider `deriveFont()`.

Answer (score 2):

See [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html). Example:

```
String m1 = "<html>You will never forget <b>" + a1 + "</b></html>";
```

Now `a1` will appear in **bold**.

Comment: In general it works, but seems, not for [JTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231750/jtextfield-together-with-html-tags).